# Static library private header - import inside library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I've got static library that has file first.h that is public and second.h which is private. In file first.h i would like to #import "second.h", but i can't (error: first.h file not found). The question is what to do with such case?

I wouldn't like to make second.h public, because i don't want it to be used outside of framework, but i would like to use it inside framework.

Any help welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can't import private files of static library. To do it one have either to move file from private to public in the library project settings or use another class to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1):

import second.h inside first.m.  Your first.h/.m would look like the following.

```
//First.h

@interface First : NSObject

@end

//First.m

#import "Second.h"
@implementation 

@end
```

Comment: Wow, how did you dig this question - it's one year old. Anyway, your answer is not correct, because as i wrote you cannot import it - it's private in static library.

Comment: What in second.h do you need in the declaration of first.h?  If its a class you can just use the @class identifier to tell the compiler that an import is coming later.  Ideally you would need to use second.h in the implementation of first so you can reference things in the private api.  I found this question googling something else.